# High number of open files for tomcat using jersey

Tags: java-8, tomcat8, jersey-client, filehandle

The Versions:

Tomcat: 8.0.23
Jersey: 2.22.1
JDK: 1.8.0_45

Problem Description:
When running an application that uses Server Sent Event Client in Jersey and Event Source to connect as listeners to an event source, the Tomcat environment creates an excessive number of file handles, around 1.3 Million, before the environment finally faults and stops responding. I have noted that there seem to be a lot of "duplicate" file references to tomcat jar and resources files. For example, I was able to count 10,444 references to the following files. It seems like there are around 2-3 copies of these references per connection. We have around 4,000 listeners before the system starts to become unresponsive.

Does anyone know of an existing issue/bug or configuration change that might help control the number of file handles or at least reduce the references?

Comment: Correction - Using Server Sent Event Client in Jersey and Event Source, not Jersey RS originally stated in the question.

Comment: edit your question with the above comment.

Comment: any solution for this one...?